# Java Webstart Reporting Wrong Bootloader options

Tags: java, constants, java-web-start, bootloader

I have problem running a Java RCP application via Java Webstart.

This works for others in the team, but not for me. (don't you just love those sort of problems)

I believe the problem is that it is downloading the 32 bit version of the application, not the 64 bit.

When I look at the webstart .log file on my machine I can see the following.

```
!SESSION 2012-07-06 16:24:37.672 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_32
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
```

So I think the problem is OS-win32, WS=win32.

My machine is a windows 7 64 bit.

Has anyone got any ideas of how I should proceed?

Comment: What version of JRE do you have on your machine? jre-6u32-windows-i586, jre-6u32-windows-x64 or jre-6u32-windows-ia64?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bootloader constants appear to be misleading as when printed the environment variables for the JVM running webstart reported:

OS: Windows 7
Arch: amd64

We tracked the issue down to the relevant SWT jars for the user environment not being downloaded (to add to the fun this is an RCP app deployed via webstart).

In the relevant jnlp file we had the following sections:

```
<resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_${org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86.version}.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Windows" arch="x86_64">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_${org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86.version}.jar"/>
</resources>

<resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_${org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86.version}.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Windows" arch="x86_64">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_${org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86.version}.jar"/>
</resources>
```

For most people this was fine as the 32bit jre would download the resource for the x86 architecture and all was well.

The problem on David's machine was running a 64bit JVM and it reports the arch property was being reported as amd64 and not x86_64 (despite it being an Intel cpu).

Changing the resources section to look like the following resolves the issue:

```
<resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_${org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86.version}.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Windows" arch="x86_64">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_${org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86.version}.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_${org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86.version}.jar"/>
</resources>

<resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_${org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86.version}.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Windows" arch="x86_64">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_${org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86.version}.jar"/>
</resources>
<resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">
    <jar href="plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_${org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86.version}.jar"/>
</resources>
```