# Webstart: What os and arch does my system return?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

The [JNLP specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html) allows for tag elements to be specified per the system's OS and architecutre.

How do I find out what Java Webstart thinks is my computer's OS and architecture? Is there a way to programmatically view or extract this value somehow? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use 
`System.getProperty("os.name")`

for the OS and

`System.getProperty("os.arch")`

for the architecture, although this will need to be in the web start app itself.

Comment: This should be added as an addendum:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374319/java-webstart-reporting-wrong-bootloader-options